# Getting a type by name and casting deserialized json data to that object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I may be approaching this incorrectly but I have an HTTP endpoint that is going to be receiving a JSON payload with an anonymous object of data and a name parameter that defines what type it should be cast to. The trouble is I'm not quite sure how to deserialize it dynamically to accept that type. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
// Get request body
RequestBodyObject body = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<RequestBodyObject>();

var assemblyName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
Type typeObject = Type.GetType($"MyNamespace, {assemblyName}");

// Cast data obtained
var specificObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeObject>(body.Data.ToString());
```

My problem of course is that I cannot use typeObject in between the <> part of my Json convert line. If I specify a static object in that place my code works fine but I'm looking for a dynamic solution since any type of object from a certain set could be passed in just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try;

```
var specificObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body.Data.ToString(),typeObject);
```

Also, you don't get any type with;

```
Type typeObject = Type.GetType($"MyNamespace, {assemblyName}");
```

You should specify type name and it would look like;

```
var typeObject = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("JsonObject");
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my first issue with the dynamic runtime cast. I ran into another issue with the cast however on this issue,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271723/dynamic-casting-json-doesnt-create-the-same-object-as-an-explicit-cast