# dynamic casting Json doesn't create the same object as an explicit cast

Tags: c#, json, casting

I had this issue I was working through where I needed to deserialize my JSON into a dynamic type and I've got that worked out with this now,

```
var typeObject = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("SalesForceEndpoints.Models.BaseAccount");
var accountToCreate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body.Data.ToString(), typeObject);

var result = client.Create(accountToCreate);  // This line fails because of the type
```

I can see that it successfully creates an object of my custom BaseAccount type. However when I am trying to pass it to the API I am using in Salesforce it fails. I tested explicitly casting to the type and it works fine like this,

```
var stronglyTypedAccountToCreate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseAccount>(body.Data.ToString());

var result2 = client.Create(stronglyTypedAccountToCreate); // This succeeds
```

When looking at both of my objects in Visual Studio they appear to be the same at first glance,

[image: Object Comparison]

And then I noticed this on my watch under the Type column,

[image]

The dynamically cast object is being listed as

**object {SalesForceEndpoints.Models.BaseAccount}**

and the explicitly cast object is being listed as

**SalesForceEndpoints.Models.BaseAccount**

I'm almost positive this is what is preventing me from executing my call succesfully, any ideas what is going wrong here and how I can execute the dynamic runtime cast to simulate an explicit compile time cast?

---

**--- EDIT ---**

I found out part of the issue. When I was calling into the Create function the create function was trying to extract the generic type and when it was dynamically cast it came through as object here instead of Account.

```
public IResponse<string> Create<T>(T obj) where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        var typeName = typeof(T).Name.Replace("Base", "");
        var result = _api.Create(typeName, obj);
        return new SuccessResponse<string>(ResponseResult.Success, result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new FailureResponse<string>(ResponseResult.Failure, $"Unable to create record. | {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Still a little curious if anyone knows why as to how a dynamic cast to an object comes through as object {ModelObject} rather than just ModelObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change it

```
var typeName = typeof(T).Name.Replace("Base", "");
```

to

```
var typeName = obj.GetType().Name.Replace("Base", "");
```

Because `T` will be evaluated as `System.Object`, you are not passing a known type to generic function and `T` stays with `System.Object`. If want to use generics, you should specify `T` in the compiler time.

Comment: Thanks so much this is exactly the issue I was dealing with. Can you explain a little bit more to me as to why typeof(T) gets evaluated to System.Object rather than the type passed at runtime? Is that always the case with Generics?

Comment: Because you are not passing a known type to generic function and "T" stays with "System.Object". If you use generics, you should specify "T" in the compiler time.